# InvalidArgumentException in ControllerResolver in Silex

Tags: php, controller, silex

I'm newbie in working with framework and Silex,
I Trying to work with Silex and write my first project.

I use this `silex-bootstrap` : https://github.com/fbrandel/silex-boilerplate

and now in my `app/app.php` :

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
// Twig Extension
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views',
));

// Config Extension
$app->register(new Igorw\Silex\ConfigServiceProvider(__DIR__."/config/config.yml"));

$app->get('/admin', new App\Controller\Admin\AdminDashboard());

return $app;
```

and in `app/Controller/Admin/AdminDashboard.php` :

```
<?php


namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;
use Silex\ControllerCollection;

class AdminDashboard implements ControllerProviderInterface {


    function __construct()
    {
        return "Dashboard";

    }

    function index()
    {
        return "Index Dashboard";
    }

    public function connect(Application $app)
    {
        return "OK";
    }


}
```

When I trying to access to site I get this error:
`http://localhost/project/public`

```
InvalidArgumentException in ControllerResolver.php line 69:
Controller "App\Controller\Admin\AdminDashboard" for URI "/admin" is not callable.
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a controller *provider* as the actual controller. These are two different things. The provider simply registers controllers with your silex app. Your provider should look something like this:

```
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;

class AdminDashboardProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
    public function connect(Application $app)
    {
        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory']();

        $controllers->get('/', function() {
            return 'Index Dashboard';
        });

        return $controllers;
    }
}
```

Then you should mount that controller provider to your app in `app/app.php`.

```
$app->mount('/admin', new AdminDashboardProvider());
```

Obviously, this is not very elegant once you get more than a few controllers or if your controllers get big. That's where [`ServiceControllerServiceProvider`](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/service_controller.html) comes in. It allows your controllers to be separate classes. I typically use a pattern like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;

class AdminDashboardProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface, ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Application $app)
    {
        $app['controller.admin.index'] = $app->share(function () {
            return new AdminIndexController();
        });
    }

    public function connect(Application $app)
    {
        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory']();

        $controllers->get('/', 'controller.admin.index:get');

        return $controllers;
    }

    public function boot(Application $app)
    {
        $app->mount('/admin', $this);
    }
}
```

The controller looks like this:

```
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

class AdminIndexController
{
    public function get()
    {
        return 'Index Dashboard';
    }
}
```

Then you can register it with your app in `app/app.php` like:

```
$app->register(new AdminDashboardProvider());
```